# How to Display an image next to the cursor when dragging?

Tags: .net, winforms

Can anyone tell me how can I display an image next to the cursor like Vista (When dragging a file to folder it shows a "Copy to..." tooltip)?

Comment: Using what technology? HTML? Windows Forms?

Comment: Windows Forms, C#, FW 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adamroot/archive/2008/02/15/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-part-3.aspx

**Update:** You need to apply the following modifications in SwfDragSourceHelper.cs to enable WinXP support.

```
public static void AllowDropDescription(bool allow)
{
    IDragSourceHelper2 sourceHelper = new DragDropHelper() as IDragSourceHelper2;
    if (sourceHelper != null)
        sourceHelper.SetFlags(allow ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your link. Its exactly what I wanted. But one more question can I use APIs used in this article in Windows XP?

Comment: Yes, with some small modifications. In general you need to disable IDragSourceHelper2 support, and use IDragSourceHelper instead. Of course all logic related to drag descriptions are also not needed in XP. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer starts with:

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCursor.cur");
```

The details are explained in this article: [How To Use Custom Cursors](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors)

Comment: The problem with this is that the center of my image will be point the screen instead of the Arrow head.